# What would be the simplest solution to split this string?

Tags: javascript, split

I have more texts like:

- identifier_100D_200A
- identifier_400D_500A

I want to have texts like:

- 100D_200A
- 400D_500A

How can I cut down the identifier_ from the string with the most simple solution and store it in a new variable ?

Comment: `str.replace('identifier_', '')` should do that :)

Comment: Who in heaven's name *upvoted* this question? The most trivial amount of research would have found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str="identifier_100D_200A";
var n=str.replace("identifier_","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the length of "identifier_" (11 characters) you can also use [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
var str = "identifier_100D_200A";
str = str.substr(11);
```